# How can I import a complex model with materials from blender to unity?

Tags: baking, unity

I've been working really hard on this 3d model for an horror game and got stuck on the importation. I've been looking for tutorials but I always have an issue. I'm trying to import all the materials by baking them on the same image, but even in 4k they appear like a grey dot in the baking result and it's not aligned with the uv editor.

[image]

[Blender File](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1x_dIsKcj1HRVFPnSENeFZQZ1WoWqONxx?usp=sharing)

Comment: Have you tried to create a texture atlas by UV unwrapping all objects on the same UV map? I'm not sure if this works well regarding the texture resolution. If you bake the whole room instead of using seamless tiles it will require a lot of texture space. For the chalkboard, you also need a good amount of texture space. Have you created only 1 student char and 1 student table? In your blend file, they are individual objects, not linked instances. Furthermore, I'm sure you only need to create one, then you can use it multiple times in your game.

Comment: You also should apply the scale and rotation to your objects. Have a look here: [Mobile game assets | Unwrap onto One Map](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Ff1IHpevXw&list=PLn3ukorJv4vu4aF4bbDA9GeX_puW7sKdE&index=3) by Grant Abbitt

Comment: Thank you for your answers :)